# How to take a slice of a Rust ndarray with a dynamic shape?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, tensor

I'd like to slice a tensor (multi-dimensional array) using Rust's [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray) library, but the catch is that the tensor is dynamically shaped and the slice is stored in a user provided variable.

If I knew the dimensionality up front, I expect I could simply do the following, where `idx` is the user provided index and `x` is a 4 dimensional tensor:

```rust
// should give a 1D tensor as a view on the last axis at index `idx`
x.slice(s![idx[0], idx[1], idx[2], ..])
```

BUT because I don't know the dimensionality up front, I cant manually unpack `idx` that way and feed it to the slice macro `s!`.

In python I might do it [this way](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs), where `idx` was a user provided tuple:

```py
# if `len(idx)` was 2 but `x.ndim` was 3, we could get a 1d tensor, of length `x.shape[-1]`
x[idx]
```

Whats the proper way to do this in Rust? The [ndarray for numpy users](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/ndarray/doc/ndarray_for_numpy_users/index.html#indexing-and-slicing) only shows how to do it with scalar values given to `s!`

Answer (score 1):

You could iteratively call `index_axis()`/`index_axis_inplace()`.  For example:

```
let mut v = x.view();
for subidx in idx {
  v.index_axis_inplace(0,subidx)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the `s!` macro](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/ndarray/macro.s.html) says:

> Slice argument constructor.
>
> `s![]` takes a list of ranges/slices/indices, separated by comma, with
> optional step sizes that are separated from the range by a semicolon. It is
> converted into a [`&SliceInfo`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/ndarray/struct.SliceInfo.html) instance.

It seems you should be able to manually create a `SliceInfo` object yourself, via `SliceInfo::new(idx)` (note that `idx` must be a slice, not a tuple).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [slice_each_axis()](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.slice_each_axis)

```
x.slice_each_axis(|ax| idx[ax])
```